# What is the oldest supported version of Django which Wagtail can run on top of?

Tags: wagtail

My company is looking at installing and using Wagtail, but we're using an older version of Django. What is the minimum required Django version which can run Wagtail?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The current version of Wagtail (2.1) is compatible with Django 1.11 and 2.0. For earlier versions of Wagtail (including 1.12 and 1.13, which are currently in Long-Term Support), see the table at: http://docs.wagtail.io/en/v2.1/releases/upgrading.html#compatible-django-python-versions

Comment: This is perfect. Thank you.